# How to prevent undefined attributes in Vue template using ESLint?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, eslint, lint

I have a `.vue` file like:

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    userName: String
  }
}
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

`name` attribute is undefined; `userName` is the expected attribute. What ESLint rule can I use to throw an Error in this case?

Comment: `vue/require-prop-types` and `vue/require-default-prop` + `vue/require-valid-default-prop`

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/98